# Is it possible to manually correct a POS tag in Spacy, and also refetch the lemma after updating the POS?

Tags: python, spacy

Let's say I have two sentences. In english `I took a fall last month.`, and in spanish `Tomé una caída el mes pasado.`

Spacy gives me the following:

```
I       took    a      fall    last   month   .
"PRON", "VERB", "DET", "NOUN", "ADJ", "NOUN", "PUNCT"
```

And

```
Tomé      una   caída   el     mes     pasado .
"PROPN", "DET", "NOUN", "DET", "NOUN", "ADJ", "PUNCT"
```

Spacy sees `Tomé` as a name, rather than as a verb. But I know it's a verb because of the English POS tagging. My issue is less with the incorrect POS(though it would be nice if it was correct), but I can fix that, however because the POS tag is incorrect, the lemma for `Tomé`, is `Tomé` instead of `tomar`.

If I do the following `doc[0].pos_ = "VERB"`, it updates the `pos_` field to be a verb, but the `doc[0].lemma_` still shows `Tomé`. Is there a way to refetch the lemma after updating the POS. Or even better, or in addition, is there a way to access lemma outside the context of a sentence. E.g. just passing in `Tomé` and `VERB` to get back `tomar`?

Interestingly, this is using `es_core_news_lg`. If I use `es_core_news_sm`, it correctly tags `Tomé` as a `VERB`, however in practice trying to figure out at runtime which model is better for a given sentence would be infeasible, so I'm defaulting to using `*_lg`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the pipeline and lemmatizer, but for the rule-based lemmatizer in `es_core_news_sm/md/lg` (tested with v3.5.0), you can modify the POS and morph and then rerun the rule-based lemmatizer for a single token.

If you just update the POS, it doesn't work for this example:

```py
doc = nlp("Tomé")
doc[0].pos_ = "VERB"
doc[0].lemma_ = nlp.get_pipe("lemmatizer").lemmatize(doc[0])[0]  # tomé
```

The lemmatizer also relies on the morphological features, so if you correct both the POS and morph, the lemmatizer can find the right rules to apply:

```py
doc = nlp("Tomé")
doc[0].pos_ = "VERB"
doc[0].set_morph("Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Person=1|Tense=Past|VerbForm=Fin")
doc[0].lemma_ = nlp.get_pipe("lemmatizer").lemmatize(doc[0])[0]  # tomar
```

The lemmatizer is designed to work on `Token` objects, so if you create a temporary doc with one token and assign the intended morph and POS, you can run the lemmatizer on it.